# Plot jqPlot bar chart in small size div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqplot

i Want to plot a simple jqplot bar chart.

But the chart must be of a fixed size which is very small **[70x50 px]**.

[image]

I am plotting the chart in a div and the div has a **fixed css which i cant change** due to specified project requirements.

**Here's the css being applied**

```
.task_brk_bar_chart {
    width:10%;
    float:left;
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding:10px 30px 10px 15px;
}
```

When i plot the chart in such a small area it gets screwed up and not viewable

i have created a fiddle showing the same

**https://jsfiddle.net/ce82natg/**

So how do i plot a bar chart in such a small area?

i dont need the legends the x/y axis just the bars ,
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for, but here is what I think is your issue:

You need to specify a height for your container

```
.task_brk_bar_chart {
   width:10%;
   float:left;
   border: 2px solid red;
   padding:10px 30px 10px 15px;
   height: 70px;
```

}

In addition I would hide the lables

```
.jqplot-xaxis-tick{ display: none}
```

The padding in your container, we should 0 to see the result you're looking for.

```
padding:0;
```

and change the following parameter in the jqPlot options

```
barWidth: 10,
```

I hope that helps

Comment: thanks for the css to hide the labels , i cant add height as the css is coming from another css file and im not allowed to edit it but i think i can try and override the css via javascript

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)